# Stackdriver logging implementation with custom commons log4j logger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, log4j, google-cloud-stackdriver, apache-commons-logging

As per [this](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java) doc, GCP is providing implementations of logback and `java.util.logger` to push logs in Stackdriver. I am using custom log4j logger. Couldn't find any related content to support for this. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct solution for this.

Combination of log4j and fluentd can help in this scenario.

It's possible to configure fluentd to export custom logs to Stackdriver. When you do this, all that is happening is fluentd is confgured to watch a log file in a specified location, then it formats the contents and exports it to Stackdriver.